# Filter duplicate rows based on a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several records (bills) that are basically duplicates of each other, except for one field, which represents the language that bill is in.

For example:

```
ID,BillID,Account,Name,Amount,Lang
1,0001,abcd,John Smith,10.99,ENG
2,0002,qwer,Jane Doe,9.99,ENG
3,0001,abcd,John Smith,10.99,SPA
4,0003,abcd,John Smith,4.99,CHI
```

All fields are strings, except ID, which is an autonumber.

In my SQL select, I have

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bills 
WHERE Account='abcd'
```

and it returns 3 rows in total, but 2 rows for the same bill. I need to return unique bills for a specific account. So in the scenario above, I want to retrieve 2 bills with billID 0003 and either SPA or ENG version of 0001, but not both.

What would by query be?

Thank you

EDIT: I cannot rely on a specific language always being there. For example, I cannot say `SELECT * FROM Bills WHERE Account='abcd' AND Lang='ENG'` because sometimes a bill may be only in one language, which is not `ENG`, and sometimes may be in several languages in any combination.

Comment: On what basis do you want to select which language to use? Alphabetical order? Bills ID - lowest or highest? Account language? Something else?

Comment: no particular preference. I need to get a bill for processing, not viewing. Language only kicks in when we render the bill in PDF, but for processing bills, language is irrelevant.

Comment: I know this won't help with the original question, but the real problem here is suboptimal database design. The best (and probably impossible) solution would be to split the original table into three tables: the first containing Bill IDs, account, name and amount; a mapping table from Bill IDs to the separate bill languages; and a third one with the bill languages themselves (like Spanish and English).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to use `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT b.*,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BillID ORDER BY Lang) as num
   FROM Bills b
   WHERE Account = 'abcd'
) tbl
WHERE num = 1
```

Comment: I like this answer the most. I've never seen this approach before. Execution plan indicates query from Eric and user2407394 are equal in query cost.

Answer (score 10):

```
select
ID,BillID,Account,Name,Amount,max(Lang)
FROM Bills 
WHERE Account='abcd'
group by BillID,Account,Name,Amount;
```

Given that you are not giving priority to any specific language if there is same bill in multiple languages. The above query will work perfect.

EDIT : Removed "ID" from group by. @Phil You are right..!!

Answer (score 6):

```
 select
 BillID,Account,Name,Amount,max(Lang)
 FROM Bills 
 WHERE Account='abcd'
 group by BillID,Account,Name,Amount;
```

Same as user2407394 except without the ID in the groupby, since that would return 3 too.

Comment: I think this (and the answer from @user2407394) would give errors since you can't select `ID` without also including it in the `group by`.

Comment: @Eric you are right. I modified the query to use Max(ID), which worked, but it presented with a little discrepancy because MAX(ID) may not always correspond to MAX(Lang). In my post, the result could be `3,0001,abcd,John Smith,10.99,ENG` because 3>1 and ENG>SPA (i know its not, but you get my point).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to just take that ID out too.

Comment: @George - yup, which is why I recommended going with ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY instead.  You could still do it with a GROUP BY as well, but it would require a subquery (select the max id, group by the other fields, then select the rows with those ids)

Answer (score -1):

Use *SELECT DISTINCT* keyword to get different values 
`SELECT DISTINCT ID,BillID,Account,Name,Amount,Lang`
`FROM Bills;`
You will get different values.

Comment: With this query, you'll receive exactly the input table. `SELECT DISTINCT BillID, Account, Name, Amount FROM Bills;` should yield the correct answer.