# Remove duplicate value on one column based on value of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table called `Table1` see below

```
PRODUCT    CUSTOMER               COMP
DICE       DAVES PET SHOP         Billed
DICE       CLAXTONS               ToT
CARDS      VIEWSONIC              NITS
CARDS      NORTHERN LIGHTS        Billed
CARDS      NORTHERN LIGHTS        NITS
BOX        TABLEAU                Billed
BOX        TABLEAU                ToT
```

There are some values where there is a duplicate in the `CUSTOMER` field but it will always contain `Billed` in at least one of the `COMP` sections if it is a duplicate, so I want the resulting query to only return the value in `COMP` where it is `Billed` for the duplicates so the resulting table would look like

```
PRODUCT    CUSTOMER               COMP
DICE       DAVES PET SHOP         Billed
DICE       CLAXTONS               ToT
CARDS      VIEWSONIC              NITS
CARDS      NORTHERN LIGHTS        Billed
BOX        TABLEAU                Billed
```

Here is the SQL I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE COMP = 'Billed'
UNION ALL
SELECT Table1_A.PRODUCT, Table1_A.CUSTOMER, Table1_A.COMP
FROM Table1 Table1_A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE COMP != 'Billed'
) Table1_B ON Table1_B.PRODUCT = Table1_A.PRODUCT 
    AND Table1_B.CUSTOMER = Table1_A.CUSTOMER
```

I thought if I put in a `UNION` and referenced both equal to `Billed` and not equal to `Billed`, then it would keep the format I'm looking for but it just repeated every single `CUSTOMER` for every single `COMP`

Comment: Sorry I added the SQL I tried, and it was just a spelling error when I was inputting the values, there is only one "NORTHERN LIGHTS" I have fixed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: No I actually saw that did try that as well, but that seems to only work where each column of the whole row is the same, for my issue only two columns of each duplicate row are the same, and the third one is different which is the dependent value I am trying to delete on

Comment: Just change the query to suit your use case - its exactly the same principle. The `row_number` approach is the way I would suggest.

Comment: I don't want to delete it from the original table though I just want a query that will show the resulting table I have above

Comment: Use the row number technique in your where clause of your select.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221543/filter-duplicate-rows-based-on-a-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aggregation for your rules:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, CUSTOMER, 
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MAX(COMP) ELSE 'Billed' END)
FROM table1 
GROUP BY PRODUCT, CUSTOMER;
```

You can also use a `UNION ALL` approach:

```
select product, customer, comp
from table1 t1
where comp = 'Billed'
union all
select product, customer, comp
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.product = t1.product and
                        tt1.customer = t1.customer and
                        tt1.comp = 'Billed'
                 );
```

Comment: Wow thanks this worked beautifully, I am a bit confused thought about why you used MAX on a VARCHAR field, does that just mean it takes the lowest value from alphabetical order? And in this case since its the same it doesn't matter which one, we are just using it to select one?

Comment: @Emitsu . . . Basically.  Technically it is the smallest value based on the *collation* but that is usually alphabetic ordering, with upper case ordered before lower case.